# Is there a non database-specific command for "insert or update"

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

we use different databases for test (mysql) and production (oracle) systems. Is there a common sql statement for updating a row if it exists and insert if not?

Regards,
Marc

Comment: Why to use Oracle if you can't use it's benefits due to mysql compatibility?

Comment: The most common commands are `merge` and `upsert`.

Comment: Why test on MySQL when production system is Oracle?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is NO. For MYSQL it will be different and for Oracle it will be different.

In MYSQL it would be like

```
INSERT INTO tabelname (id, name) 
VALUES (1, 'abc') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = id;
```

In Oracle it would be like

```
DECLARE
    x NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
    SELECT nvl((SELECT 1 FROM tabelname WHERE name = 'abc'), 0) INTO x FROM dual;

    IF (x = 1) THEN
        INSERT INTO tabelname (1,'abc')
    END IF;

END;
```

or you can use merge like this:

```
merge into tablename a
    using (select 1 id, 'abc' name from dual) b
        on (a.name = b.name)
    when not matched then
   insert( id, name)
      values( b.id, b.name)
```

Comment: why not to simply merge in oracle?

Comment: @miraclefoxx:- Yes that is also an option and infact a better one. My point was just to make OP understand that there is no common query for both MYSQL and Oracle

Comment: @miraclefoxx:- Updated with the merge option as well!

Comment: there is no common statement. And even if two databases do support MERGE the semantics might different. With MVCC and concurrency MERGE is quite hard to implement. I think in PostreSQL they decided to implement both, although usually they are quite strict about ANSII SQL  compliance.